# IBM Bluemix- PHP with backend Java process

Tags: php, ibm-cloud

I have started to deploy my PHP application on blue mix and the PHP part work great.
My PHP scripts are connecting via TCP to my own proprietary java process.
I could not find any service to bind to PHP that is simply a JVM. the nearest thing is a full java web application which is not what I need...

Can you help me here?

Answer (score 0):

the bluemix runtimes (PHP, node.js, Java liberty and so on) allows another app to connect using ports 80 and 443, because these are supposed to be web application.
Anyway you can develop and deploy an application using Java liberty runtime, using all the options provided by this runtime

https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/starters/liberty/index.html#optionsforpushinglibertyapplications

but you have to keep in mind that only port TCP 80 and 443 will be allowed to accept external connections, using application public URLs.
So you can develop an app and make it run on java liberty runtime as an application, but it will be limited to these ports.

The other solution, better, is to use a container: you can configure your container image in the way you like, and make your application running using a simple jvm.

Comment: only the PHP serves as "front-end", the Java is my back-end, which should not expose anything to the outside, only to the PHP scripts.

can you elaborate more on the container? how do I run a simple  JVM in it which is only accessible from the PHP scripts in the Web Server?

Comment: A php runtimes cannot host a jvm, so you have to use two different runtimes, making them to expose their services using TCP ports.

Docker containers (supported on Bluemix) instead allows you to have a great freedom of configuring their environment, you could think a container as a little portable live VM, you can configure as you wish.

You can start on containers from here

https://docs.docker.com/articles/basics/

https://docs.docker.com/

https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/containers/container_index.html

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to see if it fits

Comment: You UK Region does not have containers.... only the US one, my app is in the UK...
Anyway, how can I accept it if I have not find out if it works for me?

Comment: You can move your application on us, or on container, or connect them using their public addresses.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89281/discussion-between-ran-cohen-and-v-bontempi).